# What is the domain of the function f(z) = log(z) if it has a branch cut at angle alpha in rectangular coordinates?

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

What I am given:

- $log(z) = ln(r) + i\theta$ , where $(r>0, \alpha<\theta<\alpha+2\pi)$
- $log(z)=\frac{1}{2}ln(x^2+y^2)+itan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$

What I am told: Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to show that the given branch is analytic in its domain.

What I tried:

- I let $u=\frac{1}{2}ln(x^2+y^2)$ and $v=tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$
- I found the partials: $u_x=v_y= \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $u_y=-v_x=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$

My guess is domain $D=x^2+y^2>0$ and $y\neq tan(\alpha)x$. I can see that the partials are defined for the first condition. I do not know how to check the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

The domain is the complex plane with the branch cut removed.  So

$$D=\Bbb C\setminus \{r(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha):r\ge 0\}.$$

Comment: This may seem like a silly question. What method would you use to show that the partials of u and v are defined on that domain D?

Comment: Well certainly the partials exist for $u$ everywhere but $0$.  For $v$ it's a bit more problematic, since $-\pi/2<\tan^{-1}x<\pi/2$ so you may want to take a different branch of $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: By the way, I get $u_x=\frac x{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: You are right. I corrected that partials and the domain. I was confusing this problem with a similar one.